# jQuery Mobile - data-icon in a Header, adjusting the position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm building a mobile site using jQuery Mobile, however I'm having a small issue correcting the position of my 'info' button.

[Header with and without text... CLICK ME!](http://www.flickr.com/photos/100579161@N06/9634324573/)

I would like the link in the header to be the data-icon only with no text, however it will not sit inline with the header word 'Test', I'd ideally like it larger too. It sits in the right position when I add text, however retracts to the top of the page when I do not (see link^)

I'm using the following code:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-theme="z">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <a href="#" id="infoicon" data-role="button" data-icon="info" class="ui-btn-right">Hi</a>
</div>
```

I would like an info button to the right of my header with no text and for it to be inline with my title. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried ths? `data-iconpos="notext"`

Comment: Thank you, that looks a lot better now. I didn't know of that instruction :)